# Can financial transactions be handled by systems that use eventually consistent datastores?

Tags: database, transactions, acid, nosql

Is it possible to handle financial transactions on eventually consistent datastores?

My hypothesis is "no", because any two parties (buyer and seller) may need to have balances updated in a single atomic transaction, and this tran saction must have ACID semantics.  In short, the user-facing semantics are non-idempotent, so I cannot see a way to make this work.

Is it possible?  If so, how? If not, is there a proof?

Answer (score 0):

hm..I don't think eventually consistent is the problem because eventually consistent only applies to when reading you won't get the latest write (correct me if I'm wrong anywhere). I'm pretty sure writes are in the order you execute them. so assuming that, the main issue is if this eventually consistent datastore can't do transactions/not ACID.